# Nested Rails Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a resource `Library` and a resource `Books`. A library can have lots of books, obviously. Something like `Library.first.books` works perfectly.

In my `routes.rb` file I've got:

```
resources :libraries
resources :books
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is request something like `/library/3/books` and get all of the books in the library with an id of three. I tried this:

```
resources :libraries, :shallow => true do
  resources :books
end
resources :books
```

*But* when I request `/library/3/books` I get *all* of the books, not just library three's books. Is there a built-in/easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/library goes to index
/library/3 goes to show
/library/3/books goes to books with params[:id] = 3.  You must render @books = Library.find(3).books.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to build another model as a relationship model.
then use :

```
has_many :book, through: :somemodel
```

it works like tagging http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

In this way you do not need to worry about the nested routes.